# Newtonsoft JArray LINQ - Group By array with identical values

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new to LINQ and having a problem I can't seem to solve. I have a JSON array/object like this:

```
[
  {
    "items": [
      "pepperoni"
    ]
  },
  {
    "items": [
      "sausage"
    ]
  },
  {
    "items": [
      "sausage"
    ]
  },
  {
    "items": [
      "pepperoni",
      "mushrooms",
      "olives"
    ]
  },
  {
    "items": [
      "peppers",
      "spinach"
    ]
  },
  {
    "items": [
      "peppers",
      "spinach"
    ]
  },
  {
    "items": [
      "peppers",
      "spinach"
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to **GROUP BY the items combinations** and produce results like this:

*peppers,spinach - 3*

*sausage - 2*

*pepperoni - 1*

*pepperoni,mushrooms,olives - 1*

This is the Linq query I have (clearly doesn't work).

```
JArray jsonData= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(jsonString);

var queryResult =
from c in jsonData.Select(i => i["items"]).Values<string>()
group c by c
into g
orderby g.Count() descending
select new { Items = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

I find examples for every scenario *except* this one.

Comment: Does my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60247002/5519709) solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge list items into string then Group items:

```
var queryResult = from c in jsonData.Select(i => String.Join(",", i["items"]).OrderBy(o => o))
                  group c by c
                  into g
                  orderby g.Count() descending
                  select new { Items = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

It will give you desired output:

```
peppers,spinach-3
sausage-2
pepperoni-1
pepperoni,mushrooms,olives-1
```

Comment: not a bad solution. Thanks. The only draw-back is that it assumes the item combinations are in the same sequence. For example, if you had the entries "peppers,spinach" and "spinach,peppers" , they would be counted separately. But thanks for the advice.

Comment: I have updated my answer with adding `OrderBy`, now they counted as same. Could you please check?

Answer (score 0):

There's another solution with the use of [`SequenceEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_SequenceEqual__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) and [`IEqualityComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8).
This solution is longer but more complete, since it uses proper custom equality comparer.

First we need a class implementing `IEqualityComparer`

```cs
public class ItemEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<string>>
{
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<string> x, IEnumerable<string> y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null)
            return true;
        else if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;

        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<string> obj)
    {
        return obj.Select(o => o.GetHashCode()).Sum();
    }
}
```

then we can use it to group the items correctly:

```cs
var itemsGroups = jsonData.Select(i => i["items"].Values<string>()).GroupBy(l => l, l => l, (key, values) => new
{
    Key = key,
    Count = values.Count()
}, new ItemEqualityComparer());
```

This solution keeps the items inside a list so that you don't have to resplit them from the joint string.

The drawback is that is slower becausxe it has to enumerate all the items of all the lists to check that there're equals.

I hope I was helpful.